# ios/SecItemDelete not accepting a SecIdentityRef/kSecMatchItemList

Tags: iphone, ios, x509, pki

In a simple methods to delete Certs by CN (the certs have previously been put there by SecItemAdd from a PKCS12 import); I am getting the error:

> Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'SecIdentity')

Where based on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1395547-secitemdelete I think I am following the instruction:

> To delete an item identified by a transient reference, specify the
>   kSecMatchItemList search key with a reference returned by using the
>   kSecReturnRef return type key in a previous call to the
>   SecItemCopyMatching or SecItemAdd functions.

to the letter. Code below:

```
NSDictionary * attributes;
NSString * cnString = @"/CN=foo";

attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              (__bridge id)(kSecClassIdentity), kSecClass,
              cnString, kSecMatchSubjectContains,
              kSecMatchLimitAll, kSecMatchLimit,
              kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnRef,
              nil];

CFArrayRef result;
status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(attributes), 
      (CFTypeRef *)&result);

if (status == noErr) {

    for(int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(result); i++) {

        SecIdentityRef item = (SecIdentityRef) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(result, i);
        NSLog(@"Item #%d: %@", i, item);

        attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      (__bridge id)(kSecClassIdentity), kSecClass,
                      [NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge id)item], kSecMatchItemList,
                      kSecMatchLimitOne, kSecMatchLimit,
                      nil];

        status = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(attributes));

        if (status != noErr || status != errSecItemNotFound)
            NSLog(@"Delete %d/%@failed: %ld (ignored)", i,item, status);
    };
};
```

The output on the console is:

```
 Item #0: <SecIdentityRef: 0xc7359ff0>
```

straight after the find (and if the search is widened we get an array of these).

And then from deep inside Security.dylib:

> Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'SecIdentity')

To ultimately bail with:

```
 Delete 0/<SecIdentityRef: 0xc7359ff0>failed: -50 (ignored)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest GM drop. Reality is now in sync with the documentation.

Comment: I am getting this same failure under iOS 6.1.3 and iOS 7.1. Does `SecItemDelete` still work correctly for you with a match item list?

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the documentation found in the header file `SecItem.h`, part of the Security framework:

> By default, this function deletes all items matching the specified query.
>   You can change this behavior by specifying one of the follow keys:
>
> - To delete an item identified by a transient reference, **on iOS, 
>     specify kSecValueRef** with a item reference. **On OS X, give a 
>     kSecMatchItemList** containing an item reference.
> - To delete an item identified by a persistent reference, **on iOS,
>     specify kSecValuePersistentRef** with a persistent reference returned by
>     using the kSecReturnPersistentRef key to SecItemCopyMatching or
>     SecItemAdd. **On OSX, use kSecMatchItemList** with a persistent reference
>     returned by using the kSecReturnPersistentRef key with
>     SecItemCopyMatching or SecItemAdd.